# Ubuntu 10.10 - video and voice chat software

Tags: ubuntu, video, software-rec, chat, voice

Is there any software that supports voice/video chat for Yahoo or MSN accounts in Ubuntu 10.10
(something like Yahoo Messenger or MSN Messenger in Windows?)

Answer (score 3):

Empathy or Pidgin

i prefer Pidgin... :D

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin is a very good client, and handles MSN and Yahoo! both.
The Yahoo! V/V libraries need to be ported to the new framework in newer versions of Pidgin, but shouldn't pose too many problems.

[Pidgin Homepage](http://www.pidgin.im)